# Why does a function return undefined?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have an array, each value of which means a side of the world:

```js
let array = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "WEST", "EAST"];
```

If NORTH/SOUTH or EAST/WEST stand **together**, then these values are removed (SOUTH/NORTH and WEST/EAST are removed too). In this case,  the function has to return empty array, instead it returns undefined. Can anyone explain why this is happening. 
Sorry for the mistakes, I tried not to make them

```js
let array = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "WEST", "EAST"];

let obj = {
  "NORTH": 1,
  "SOUTH": -1,
  "WEST": 2,
  "EAST": -2
}

function dirReduc(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i == arr.length - 1 || !arr.length) {
      return arr;
    } else if (obj[arr[i]] + obj[arr[i + 1]] == 0) {
      arr.splice(i, 2);
      return dirReduc(arr);
    }
  }
}

console.log(dirReduc(array));
```

Comment: There's not a single return statement in that function, how do you expect anything to be returned at all?  You modify the array in place - do `dirReduc(array); console.log(array);` and see the difference.

Comment: If either of the conditions is not passed, the function is executed to the end, where you don't have a `return` statement.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the question.

Comment: After two recursive calls, your array will be empty, and so in that deepest call, the loop finishes without iteration, and then ... returns nothing (no `return`), which is `undefined`. That will be returned also in the upper levels of the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify is as following:

```
let array = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "WEST", "EAST"];

let obj = {
    "NORTH": 1,
    "SOUTH": -1,
    "WEST": 2,
    "EAST": -2
}

function dirReduc(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == arr.length - 1) {
            return arr;
        } else if (obj[arr[i]] + obj[arr[i + 1]] == 0) {
            arr.splice(i, 2);
            if (arr.length == 0)
                return [];
            return dirReduc(arr);       
        }
    }
} 

console.log(dirReduc(array));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When your recursive function splices away *all* content, like in the example, the deepest nested call of the function will not iterate the loop (as the array is empty), and return `undefined`. This value will be returned also from the point where the recursive call was made, and so also the main call will return `undefined`.

I would suggest not using recursion, but iterate backwards. That way the `splice` call does not influence the array iteration negatively, and you'll only do one sweep over the array:

```
function dirReduc(arr) {
    for (let i = arr.length-2; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (obj[arr[i]] + obj[arr[i + 1]] == 0) arr.splice(i, 2);
    }
    return arr;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array was getting down to length 0, and the for loop wasn't even running because of that.

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```